# NULL check in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please suggest whats the difference between:

1) `WHERE student.name = ISNULL(@name, student.name)`

And

2) `WHERE (student.name = @name OR @name IS NULL)`

Actually I had a issue bug assigned against my name where some of the records where skipped when I used the first method. But got corrected when I replaced it with eg 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [second parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) for `ISNULL()` is a *replacement value*, meaning the value that will be substituted if the first parameter is null.  Thus, if both `@name` and `student.name` were `null`, you'd essentially be writing:

`student.name = NULL`

Which equates to false (as `null` in SQL is considered unknown, and never *equals* anything).

In the second, you're using the `IS` operator to test for a null value, which will return `true` if `@name` is null.

Comment: for the first statement, if both are NULL, then it would be WHERE NULL = NULL

Comment: That means that when @name is null, the first query will return only where student.name is not null and the second query will return all rows.

Comment: Correct, if you're passing in a `@name` of NULL, the first query would return any non-null student (such as `'bob' = 'bob'`) where-as the second query would return *everything*, as `@name is null` is true for all rows.  Yes, it is rather an odd query.

Comment: Wow Fantastic...It really cleared my doubt. The main underlining point here was made by Mike "as null in SQL is considered unknown, and never equals anything". Even I was under the impression that NULL == NULL returns True, but its actually FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

The second statement says *Select records when student name matches @name or when no name was specified* If @name is specified, select for that name. If @name is empty, select all records. This doesn't care about what value is in the table when @name is NULL

For the first statement, if @name is NULL, it will use student.name which is the same as the current row's student.name

**When both @name and student.name are NULL**

```
WHERE student.name = @name OR @name IS NULL -- the other part of the OR is true so records will be returned
```

and

```
WHERE student.name = ISNULL(@name, student.name) becomes WHERE NULL = NULL
```

because `NULL = NULL` returns false, no records will be returned for that row

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE student.name = ISNULL(@name, student.name)
```

And

```
WHERE (student.name = @name OR @name IS NULL)
```

are equivalent except if student.name is null.

```
WHERE (student.name = @name OR @name IS NULL)
```

may be simplified :

```
WHERE COALESCE(student.name,'nul') = COALESCE(@name, student.name,'nul')
```

And

```
WHERE student.name = ISNULL(@name, student.name)
```

is equivalent to

```
WHERE (student.name = @name OR @name IS NULL AND student.name IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the difference

```
name |student.name  |first_result  |second_result |expected*
A    |A             |true          |true          |true
A    |B             |false         |false         |false
null |A             |true          |true          |true
A    |null          |false         |false         |false
null |null          |FALSE         |TRUE          |TRUE
```

*expected - expected by some folks, but not correct in our universe.

As you see, difference comes when both values are NULL, because in that case, your first WHERE evaluates into:
null = null (which is FALSE).

You can check that in SQL Server with:

```
select case when null = null then 1 else 0 end
```

which will give you 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [ANSI_NULLS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) system setting set otherwise, `null = anything` is false.

So the first query will not return any entries where `student.name` is null, even if `@name` is null, because the comparison evaluates to `where null=null` for entries where student.name is null, and `null=null` returns false

Comment: isn't it `WHERE student.name  IS NULL OR student.name = @name` ?

Comment: ...And `@Name` is null if `@Name` is not null there's no difference

Answer (score 0):

Check examples below and in your 2nd option you can check @name is null before checking name = @name.

```
declare @name varchar(10) = null
declare @table table (name varchar(10))

insert into @table 
select 'A'
UNION
SELECT null


---returns only A because null = column is always false
select * from @table where name = ISNULL(@name, name)

--returns all rows
select * from @table where (@name is null or name = @name)


set @name = 'A'
select * from @table where name = ISNULL(@name, name)
select * from @table where (@name is null or name = @name)
```